# how to select the infos where some information in another table is NULL

Tags: mysql

There are two tables in my db:

table 1

```
id name extra_id
1  name1   2
2  name2   4
3  name3   6
4  name3   2
```

table 2 called extra

```
id blah blah
1  blah1 blah2
3  blah1 blah2
5  blah1 blah2
6  blah1 blah2
```

now i want to select id:1 and id:2 and id:4 in table1 and group by extra_id, cause there's no corresponding data in table2.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you want just the id? Why the grouping then? :)

Comment: i think hes misunderstanding how the group by works, he doesnt get the selected rows because they wont return in the sql he is trying because there is no data to select on, he needs a left join.

Answer (score 0):

Use left join, which will let you still select those rows, it will just set the columns that have no data to null

```
SELECT a.*,b.*
FROM table1 as a
LEFT JOIN 
extra as b
ON a.extra_id=b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the id's in Table1 that have no corresponding row in "extra".
There's no need to group since there's only a single column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.id 
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN extra 
  ON Table1.extra_id=extra.id
WHERE extra.id IS NULL

>> 1
>> 2
>> 4
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a5e8/3).

Comment: how to write, if i want to group the ids by extra_id?

Comment: @yudun1989 Could you add exactly the result you'd want from the query to your question? Something like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a5e8/7)?